# Can $(\mathcal P(\mathbb N),\subseteq)$ be partitioned into maximal antichains?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

If you look at the set of *finite* subsets of $\mathbb N$ (side question: Is there a standard notation for that?) partially ordered by the subset relation, you see that it can be partitioned into maximal antichains (that is, you have a set of maximal antichains so that any two of them are disjunct, and their union is the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb N). One possibility (but by far not the only one) is to have each antichain consist of all sets of the same cardinality.

Also for the set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$ that are either finite or cofinite, it's not hard to define such a partition; partition the finite sets according to their cardinality, and the cofinite sets according to the cardinality of the complement.

Of course such simple strategies won't work any more with the full $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$. Indeed, I have no idea how one would either define such a partition, or prove that there doesn't exist one. Of course there's also the possibility that there exists such a partition, but you cannot explicitly specify it.

Therefore my question is: Does there exist a partition of $(\mathcal P(\mathbb N),\subseteq)$ into maximal antichains, and if so, is is possible to explicitly specify one?

Comment: One standard notation for the family of subsets of $A$ of cardinality $\kappa$ is $[A]^\kappa$, with $[A]^{<\kappa}$ for the family of subsets of $A$ of cardinality less than $\kappa$, and so on. The set of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ is then $[\Bbb N]^{<\omega}$. I have also seen $\wp_{\text{fin}}(\Bbb N)$.

Comment: I can second the notation $[\mathbb{N}]^{< \omega}$. Also, great question!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thank you. But, if the exponent is a cardinality, shouldn't it then be $[\mathbb N]^{<\aleph_0}$?

Comment: @celtschk: No: $\omega$ is a cardinal as well as an ordinal. Cardinals are just initial ordinals, and $\omega$ is an initial ordinal. Of course you can also use alephs, but there’s no real reason to do so in this context.

Comment: My preference would be for $\aleph_0$ to show that we've forgotten the order structure on $\omega$.  We use the term 'cardinal' for an initial ordinal, but I feel that it's not strictly correct to equate 'cardinal' in this sense with 'cardinality'.  Firstly, the need to choose a particular representative of each cardinality class is invalid from the point of view of structural set theory.  Secondly, in the absence of the axiom of choice, not all cardinalities need be alephs.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: The symbols definitely cannot be used interchangeably. For example, $2^\omega = \omega$, but $2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak{c}>\aleph_0$

Comment: @celtschk: You’re wrong: mine is a very standard usage. (E.g., Ken Kunen’s *Set Theory* (1980), Lemma I.10.19(1): ‘Each $\omega_\alpha$ is a cardinal’.) $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$ in cardinal arithmetic and $\omega$ when it’s ordinal arithmetic, and context almost always makes it obvious which is intended.

Comment: @John: My preference is for $\omega$ unless there is a truly overriding reason to muck about with alephs. I couldn’t care less about structural set theory, and the fact that not all cardinalities need be well-orderable seems to me completely irrelevant: the set $[A]^{<\omega}$ doesn’t depend on choice.

Comment: @JohnGowers The notation using ordinals is more useful than the notation with cardinals because it has additional applications.  For instance, you can consider the set $[\kappa]^{\omega+\omega}$ of all subsets  of $\kappa$ of order type exactly $\omega+\omega.$ Or, using $\lt,$ you can look at the set  $[\kappa]^{\lt\omega+\omega}$ of all subsets  of $\kappa$ of order type less than $\omega+\omega.$There' s no way to write this with the notation based on just cardinals.

Comment: @MitchellSpector: Actually, since we were talking about subsets if given *cardinality*, rather than of given *order type*, your argument is actually an argument *against* using ordinal notation for cardinality. In particular, since the cardinality of $\omega+\omega$ is still $\aleph_0$, the subsets of order type $\omega+\omega$ should definitely be in $[X]^{\aleph_0}$. If not distinguishing between $\omega$ and $\aleph_0$, you then also cannot distinguish in notation between the subsets of $X$ of order type $\omega$ ($[X]^\omega$) and the subsets of cardinality $\aleph_0$ ($[X]^{\aleph_0}$).

Comment: I'm not suggesting using ordinal notation for cardinality, merely that an order-typed-based concept (using ordinals) is more useful than a cardinality-based concept (using cardinals), since the ordinal version lets you express finer variations. This is true as long as the base set $X$ is an ordinal (or has a natural ordering).

Comment: You could write the set of countable subsets of $\kappa$ as $[\kappa]^{\lt\omega_1}.$ Often I think some other notation, such as $\mathscr{P}_{\aleph_1}(\kappa)$ or $\mathscr{P}_{\lt\aleph_1}(\kappa),$ would be defined and used.

Comment: @MitchellSpector: "I'm not suggesting using ordinal notation for cardinality" — but that's exactly what the discussion was about. And $[\kappa]^{<\omega_1}$ would also include the finite subsets, which $[\kappa]^{\aleph_0}$ doesn't.

Comment: The original problem was about the collection of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}.$ You can think of that as the collection of sets of finite cardinality, but you can also think of it as the collection of sets of order type less than $\omega.$ Either version can be used as a basis for generalization.

Comment: @MitchellSpector: OK, that's a different argument for the specific notation $[\mathbb N]^{<\omega}$, but not the one Brian M. Scott used, and that was discussed later (*in particular* in the comment you directly responded to).

Comment: The comment I replied to was about the use of ordinals vs. cardinals in the notation. Now I don't really think the notation is a big deal as long as the author is clear -- I was just pointing out that it can be useful to pick a notation that lets you distinguish between sets based on order type if you want to, rather than just on the basis of cardinality.  (This happens a lot in connection with Ramsey-style partition relations.)